# Как изменить цвет svg для hover? Вот код моей иконки

Tags: css3, html5, svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 49 49"
   height="49"
   width="49"
   id="svg53"
   version="1.1">
  <metadata
     id="metadata59">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs57" />
  <image
     y="0"
     x="0"
     id="image61"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADEAAAAxCAYAAABznEEcAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ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"
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     height="49"
     width="49" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Обновил ответ и там уже та картинка на `svg` что и в вашем вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не объект `svg` а просто картинка, и как вы хотите изменить цвет картинки?

Вот пример как менять свойство объекта `svg` (в нашем случае цвет), это не картинка (image) и его цвет можно изменить.

```css
/* HOVER COLOR */

a svg:hover #facebook,
a svg:hover #instagram { 
  fill: #111;
}

/* GENERAL STYLES */

body { 
  background-color: #bad0b8;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FC7864, #FDA366);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FC7864, #FDA366);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FC7864, #FDA366);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #FC7864, #FDA366);
  background-image: linear-gradient(right, #FC7864, #FDA366);
}
article { 
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 60px auto; 
  text-align: center;
  zoom: 2;
}
a { 
  outline: none; 
  border: 0; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}
a svg #facebook,
a svg #instagram { 
  transition: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<article>
<a href="https://facebook.com/username" target="_blank">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve">
   <path id="facebook" fill="#ffffff" d="M17.252,11.106V8.65c0-0.922,0.611-1.138,1.041-1.138h2.643V3.459l-3.639-0.015
 c-4.041,0-4.961,3.023-4.961,4.961v2.701H10v4.178h2.336v11.823h4.916V15.284h3.316l0.428-4.178H17.252z"/>
  </svg>
</a>

<a href="https://instagram.com/username" target="_blank">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve">
   <path id="instagram" fill="#ffffff" d="M22.107,3.415H7.893c-2.469,0-4.479,2.007-4.479,4.477v4.73v9.486c0,2.469,2.01,4.479,4.479,4.479h14.215
 c2.469,0,4.479-2.01,4.479-4.479v-9.486v-4.73C26.586,5.421,24.576,3.415,22.107,3.415 M23.393,6.086l0.512-0.004v0.511v3.416
 l-3.916,0.014l-0.012-3.928L23.393,6.086z M11.693,12.622c0.742-1.028,1.945-1.7,3.307-1.7s2.564,0.672,3.307,1.7
 c0.484,0.67,0.771,1.49,0.771,2.379c0,2.248-1.828,4.078-4.078,4.078c-2.248,0-4.078-1.83-4.078-4.078
 C10.922,14.112,11.211,13.292,11.693,12.622 M24.328,22.107c0,1.225-0.994,2.219-2.221,2.219H7.893
 c-1.225,0-2.219-0.994-2.219-2.219v-9.486h3.459C8.832,13.356,8.664,14.159,8.664,15c0,3.494,2.842,6.335,6.336,6.335
 s6.336-2.842,6.336-6.335c0-0.842-0.17-1.645-0.467-2.379h3.459V22.107z"/>
  </svg>
</a>
 
  
</a>
</article>
```

А вот это ваша картинка но уже полностью на `svg`:
И теперь его цвет можно менять, оно уже не картина (png). и это делается свойством `fill` который задает цвет наполнения `svg` объекта․

```css
.svg_span:hover g{
  fill: #789654;
}
```

```html
<span class="svg_span">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="49.000000pt" height="49.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 49.000000 49.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.10, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2011
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,49.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M223 408 c-68 -69 -76 -82 -142 -232 -39 -88 -69 -161 -68 -163 2 -1
75 29 163 68 150 66 163 74 232 142 39 39 72 77 72 84 0 28 -28 10 -95 -58
-67 -68 -88 -82 -222 -139 -39 -17 -42 -17 -56 -2 -13 15 -11 27 25 107 33 75
52 103 114 165 41 42 74 81 74 88 0 27 -29 9 -97 -60z m-133 -327 c0 -5 -7
-11 -15 -15 -15 -5 -20 5 -8 17 9 10 23 9 23 -2z"/>
<path d="M272 367 c-70 -70 -86 -97 -59 -97 20 0 160 146 153 159 -12 18 -19
14 -94 -62z"/>
<path d="M307 332 c-65 -65 -81 -92 -54 -92 16 0 147 131 147 148 0 26 -28 9
-93 -56z"/>
<path d="M342 297 c-70 -70 -86 -97 -59 -97 20 0 160 146 153 159 -12 18 -19
14 -94 -62z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо) а где Вы конвертировали мою png в svg?

Comment: @MishY Вот тут `http://picsvg.com/`